# Is it appropriate to ask discussion-related questions?

Tags: discussion

For example, I would like to ask math.stackexchange (roughly):

> What is exciting about primitive roots?

or

> What are some clever uses of primitive roots?

I fear it's not a question that follows the single-selected-answer format. Thoughts?

Comment: From [the Math.SE FAQ "tour"](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour): "We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how: ... This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."  To reinforce @Asaf's answer below, much more context would be necessary to pose a good Question.  Of course the search function might help you find a large number of previous Questions about primitive roots, and this may well satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: The problem I'm finding is that, while there's many people here that could give great insight into a topic, the get-straight-to-the-point-problem-solving format doesn't tend to leak very much of that valuable insight. I was hoping this might be a better way to eke out that class of information.

Comment: It might be possible to influence the sharing of "insights" by upvoting posts which have this.  Many Answers are aimed at providing "hints" instead of full solutions, and this may tend to encourage brevity over fuller exposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That would be, by definition, too broad or unclear.

Some "open questions" are okay, but they need to be well-motivated. In the distant past, when the site was much smaller, these type of questions were much more accepted and many of them were received quite well in terms of views, votes and answers. Nowadays... not as much.